# How can I obtain app energy impact data from the command line or applescript?

Tags: applescript, battery, command-line

Does anyone know how to access the "Energy Impact" data used to determine "Apps Using Significant Energy" displayed in the battery menu bar? I'd like to use it in a shell-script/applescript.

[image]

Comment: Probably it uses /usr/bin/powermetrics, but actually i haven't been able to figure out how those data are processed.

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/150617/34902

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the raw data used for the Energy calculations can be obtained using the **powermetrics** CLI:

```
*** Running tasks ***

Name             PID    CPU ms/s  User%  Deadlines (<2 ms, 2-5 ms)  Wakeups (Intr, Pkg idle)
kernel_task      0      41.14     0.00   267.46  0.20               2290.48 1533.24
WindowServer     186    99.50     73.47  54.93   15.58              73.51   67.31
Terminal         53513  105.38    88.85  0.00    0.00               12.78   10.99
```

Comment: Not exactly accessible via Shell scripting, my dear Watson :-)

Comment: @patrix I guess I missed that bit… (rewritten answer)