# Energy impact from terminal

Tags: energy

Is there a command available that displays the Energy Impact from the terminal?
`Top` doesn't display this info.

Comment: You mean other the the Activity Monitor.app ?

Answer (score 14):

*Top* will do it. However, this is not documented in the man page.

Example:

> top -stats pid,command,power -o power -l 0

And of course you can grep the process of your choice

---

You can also use the *powermetrics* command to get some general info.

See documentation via man or [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/powermetrics.1.html)

A nice example can be found [here](http://randomfoo.net/2013/11/08/more-on-os-x-mavericks-power-usage)

> powermetrics -i 1000 --poweravg 1 | grep 'Average cumulatively decayed power score' -A 20

Comment: how to get average energy using `top`